# Running python on a server computer 24 hours

Tags: python, server

Is there such service (free/paid) allow me to upload my python program (which it may have to support the library that I import), and just run on its server end 24 hours non-stop please?

The idea is this python program will keep on running and rely me information.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/python). They have a free tear, and it integrates with git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,There are many platform to upload your code in cloud and runs non-stop.
AWS and GCP(Google cloud platform) are the best services which provide these facilities.

You can refer this link for AWS [AWS free tier usage](https://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/?ft=nf)

For GCP you can refer this link [GCP free tier usage](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many services, but I would recommend using a linux VPS so you can control your server and run many python programs as you want 24/7.

DigitalOcean providing a great service like a small VPS with good specifications for python programs and the price is low as $5/month and you can choose your linux distribution + datacenter region and will take only few seconds to setup your server.

Here is my referral link ([Click Here](https://m.do.co/c/f1e70161af09)) using my link will give you $10 credits and I will have benefits as well.

good luck!